# Music player that supports multiple genres

Tags: rhythmbox, music, banshee, amarok

Is there a music player for Ubuntu that either supports multiple genres or has a plug-in to support them? Say I have a song with the genre "Metal/Instrumental" (the separator isn't really important). I would like it to show up in both the "Metal" and "Instrumental" genres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhythmbox performs search by "all fields" by default. Which means that it will search every shown field (columns are customizable), this way if a song matches at least one of your search criteria, it will be shown in the results list.

Let's say: I have songs with the "Disco" and the "Italo-Disco" tags in the "Genre" field, as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

When I run a search for "Italo", only these songs that matches that search criteria will be shown in the list as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

But if I run a search for the "Disco" tag, the results will show both "Disco" and "Italo-Disco" results, as shown here:

[image]

Other search results for tags in different fields/columns will do the same, see this screenshot for the "Techno" tag in the "Genre Field".

[image]

For customizing your fields list simply go to Edit/Preferences in order to check which fields you wish to be shown in the list in the "General" Tab:

[image]

If your Rythmbox's search results won't result in what you expect, you may wish to uninstall and reinstall Rhythmbox. Please let us know if you succeed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try Miro.  Its similar to Media Monkey.  For more info, and to download Miro visit their [Website](http://www.getmiro.com/download/).

Also Try Clementine

> Clementine is a multiplatform music player. It is inspired by Amarok
>   1.4, focusing on a fast and easy-to-use interface for searching and playing your music.

To install just click [**Clementine** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clementine/)

<sup>Source:Clementine</sup>